# Unable to locate ntpd package

Tags: ntp

I am trying to install ntp for my server. However, on running `sudo apt-get install ntpd`
i get the response Unable to locate package ntpd. I have run `sudo apt-get update` and the problem still remains

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Install ntp server**

Type the following command:

```
apt-get install ntp
```

Answer (score -2):

Try the following sequence :

`sudo apt-get update`

then

`sudo apt-get install ntp`

will be succeeded...

Comment: This is exactly what the earlier answer says, plus what OP already has done.

Comment: @SorenA, This is also an answer but it should n't be unique from others to solve the purpose. Also, I give the correct package name to get the installation succeeded (Though that was already answered, is it bad to answer here?).